# Does $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} \frac{f(x)}{g(x,y)}$ that equals to $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} \frac{g(x,y)}{f(x)}$ mean that the limit equals to 1?

Tags: limits

Using L'hopital rule: $\lim_{x \to x_i, y \to y_i} \frac{x-x_i}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2}} = \lim_{x \to x_i, y \to y_i} \frac{\frac{d(x-x_i)}{dx}}{\frac{d\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2}}{dx}} = \lim_{x \to x_i, y \to y_i} \frac{1}{\frac{x-x_i}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2}}} = \lim_{x \to x_i, y \to y_i} \frac{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2}}{x-x_i} = 1?$

When a limit equals itself$^{-1}$, is that limit equal to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly observe that by $x-x_i=u$ and $y-_i=v$ we have

$$\lim_{x \to x_i, y \to y_i} \frac{x-x_i}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2}} =\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)} \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}} $$

which doesn't exist (just consider path $u=v=t\to 0^+$ and path $u=v=t\to 0^-$).

For the general question when

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} F(x,y)=L\neq 0$$

exists then by reciprocal law for limits

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} \frac{1}{F(x,y)}=\frac 1L\neq 0$$

and thus when both limits exist

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} F(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)} \frac{1}{F(x,y)}$$

implies $L^2=1$.

Comment: What if $L=-1$?

Comment: @zkutch Yes of course, you are right, I fix that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** when we have $a = \frac{1}{a}$, then it gives $a^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

L'hopital rule is for one variable not multiple variables,
you have a problem lim (x->x0) lim(y->y0) f(x,y) =/= lim(y->y0) lim (x->x0) f(x,y)

in the first case the limit is 1 and in the second case lim(y->y0) sqrt((y-y0)^2)/0 which is infinite.

So the answer is no, the limit for multiple variables you need to transform those variables into the polar coordinates and proof that a limit doesn't depend on particular a vector direction.